# Iterating through a list to produce all possible combinations of elements in a list?

Tags: python, list, loops, while-loop

I am trying to print out all possible combinations of the elements in a list.

```
import random

def fun(lst, run):
    i = 0
    while i < run:
        newList = lst
        NewNumbers = newList[-1:] + newList[:-1] #shifts each element in the to the right
        lst = NewNumbers
        print(lst)
        i += 1

fun([1, 2, 0], 3)
```

As the initial list [1, 2, 0]. This programme produces the output

```
>>>>>>>>
[0, 1, 2]
[2, 0, 1]
[1, 2, 0]
>>>>>>>>
```

I have had to physically change the list from [1, 2, 0] to something else like [1, 1, 0] to get the other possible combinations

```
>>>>>>>>
[0, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 0]
>>>>>>>>
```

and then go on to change the list to `[2, 2, 0], [0, 0, 2]` etc. to get other combinations and this is very time consuming and not easy to do once I increase the list to 4 elements like `[1, 2, 0, 1]`

I have been able to find a way to do this using python's intertools

```
import itertools
def fun(lst):
        all_possible_combinations = set(itertools.product(lst, repeat=3)) #repeat = number of elements
        return all_possible_combinations
print(fun([0, 1, 2]))
```

This produces exactly what I am looking for, it generates all the possible types of combinations of the elements 0, 1, 2

```
{(0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (0, 2, 1), (1, 0, 2), (0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 2), (2, 0, 1), (1, 2, 0), (2, 0, 0), (1, 2, 1), (0, 0, 2), (1, 2, 2), (2, 0, 2), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 0), (2, 1, 2), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0), (2, 2, 2), (2, 1, 0), (2, 2, 1), (2, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (2, 2, 0), (0, 1, 0)}
```

I am trying to produce all these combinations through a loop that goes through iterations e.g. first iteration (0, 1, 1) then second iteration (0, 1, 2) as shown below:

```
(0, 1, 1)
(0, 1, 2) 
(1, 0, 0)
(1, 0, 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pure python equivalent of [itertools.product()](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) is shown in the docs:

```
def product(*args, **kwds):
    # product('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax Ay Bx By Cx Cy Dx Dy
    # product(range(2), repeat=3) --> 000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111
    pools = map(tuple, args) * kwds.get('repeat', 1)
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
    for prod in result:
        yield tuple(prod)
```

Answer (score 1):

this method uses recursive function to generate the list of all combinations, then u can iterate over it.

```
def product(lst, current, rslt):
    if len(current) >= len(lst) - 1:
        for item in lst:
            rslt += [current + [item]]
    else:
        for item in lst:
            product(lst, current + [item], rslt)

rslt = []
product([0, 1, 2], [], rslt)
for p in rslt:
    print p
```

Comment: The question already contains this answer, they are trying to do it with a loop

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the code for itertools product here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

If you want your function to have the same variable names as yours, here's a modified version of the product code to do what you want:

```
def fun(lst, run):
    pools = [lst] * run
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
    for prod in result:
        yield(tuple(prod))

print(list(fun([1, 2, 0], 3)))
```

output:

```
[(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 0), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 2), (1, 0, 0), (2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 1, 0), (2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 0), (2, 0, 1), (2, 0, 2), (2, 0, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 0), (0, 2, 1), (0, 2, 2), (0, 2, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 0)]
```